# Program to obfuscate files before compilation?

Tags: java, obfuscation

I am working with ForgeGradle (Minecraft Forge modding platform).

I'd like to obfuscate my mod before publishing but the nature of Forge platform won't allow me to do it by simply running program like ProGuard after compilation (with defined libraries).

Why?
The structure goes like this:
Mod -> Forge -> Minecraft

Since Minecraft uses its own obfuscated classes and ForgeGradle compilator is not DIRECTLY obfuscating Mod's code to fit with Minecraft's one, it is not possible to use MC.jar as library while using ProGuard. Compiled Forge Mod is actually decoded by Forge in runtime using SRG names. The logic behind this is not easily explainable so I'll just note: I cannot obfuscate .jar in a way to fit with libraries.

So I though - I could just take my mod's code (.java files) and rename all fields/methods/classes that are MINE before Forge compilation.
Is there a software that would allow me to pick number of .java files and "obfuscate" them in a way to not reaname references that don't belong to them?

**EDIT (more explanation):**

Mod's code has 3 states: Development, Compiled, Running.

I will try to give an example:
Let's say there is a decompiled method ItemSword.onHit() inside Minecraft.jar
And its compiled (obfuscated) version look like this: bca.aa(), also all packages are lost (flattened).

In mod's development state of code (.java) to make reference to it we simply make: ItemSword.onHit()

When we compile mod the call will look like this (.class): ItemSword.func_ab4234() - this is the SRG I was talking about.

Now when the mod will be loaded to game, forge will translate "ItemSword" to "bca" and "func_ab4234()" to "aa()"

Because of this I can't even add proper library - there IS NONE. I will always get (in ProGuard) NoClassDefFound Warning and I can't ignore it (it will crash compilation).

So after this edit - Is it still possible to make obfuscation with ProGuard (considering I cannot have "good" library assigned)?

Comment: Sure, you can obfuscate your source files before compilation. You can eliminate all useful information based on class, method, field or variable names. However, some things can only be obfucated in the byte code (in the compiled .class file). Additionally, make sure not to include any debugging information when compiling.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is how to do it VERY fast, and possibly random? I am using Eclipse and I know Refractor tool, which is pretty much exacly what I need, but it just need to do it automatically with few click on all selected files. Anyone knows if thing like this exists?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the proguard options?
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html

e.g. for Serializable classes and other stuff put this to your proguard configuration (you also can preserve complete classes if you like):

```
<!-- With this code serializable classes will be backward compatible -->
<keepnames implements="java.io.Serializable"/>

<!-- or for native access:-->
<keepclasseswithmembernames>
 <method access="native"/>
</keepclasseswithmembernames>

<!--Preserve all public classes, and their public and protected fields and methods.--> 
<keep access="public">
 <field access="public protected"/>
 <method access="public protected"/>
</keep>
```

Comment: I've made edit in question. Could you please confirm it is still possible what you are suggesting above? If so, I will get to learning more about keep options.

Comment: one thing for clarification: if you don't obfuscate your mod, it works, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question, you want to obfuscate your own code, not anything beyond that. That's what ProGuard is actually quite good at. Let's assume you created your classes in the packages `com.foo` and `com.bar`. You can use this simple ProGuard command to only obfuscate your own classes:

```
-keep class !com.foo.**,!com.bar.** { *; }
```

It tells ProGuard to not obfuscate any members of classes which do not belong to either `com.foo` or `com.bar`.

If you are getting `NoClassDef` errors, you added the wrong library. I guess you are using some kind of IDE (perhaps eclipse). Have a look at the libraries your project references to find the correct library classpath (e.g. a jar file). You basically need to find the classpath used for compiling your code, ProGuard will take that as well and everything should work.

Comment: That is the problem, there is no library that can handle compiled mod. Read my edit again.
There is ONLY library for Development state of mod and for running mod (totally obfuscated). There is no library for just compiled mod. Compiled mod is being loaded by ForgeModLoader and is recompiled in runtime (on startup) and for that there is no .jar. It's all done by Transformers (:D) using names saved in .srg (like .txt) file. There is no possible way I can obtain a "correct" library. Is there really no eclipse refractor-based obfuscator?

Comment: @Ernio Does the forge framework modify the class files **after** compilation?

Comment: Yes, when creating a mod you are working in fully deobfuscated workspace, then when you compile - your mod is compiled into Forge-universal-names that no matter what version you use, the mod will always stay the same (with every Minecraft update method names change, Forge doesn't). Then when you put your mod into user-end enviroment the Forge loads mods and TRANSLATES them into Minecraft-readable classes (depending on version, the translation is different). The translation happens in class-loading phase and is done by ASM. Because of this I don't have any library I could use in ProGuard.

Comment: That is why I am looking for actually doing all my private obfuscation before I even compile mod - in .java files. I can't belive there is no (eclipse-like)refractor-obfuscation program (or plugin for eclipse). I've been looking for hours. If anyone know something, please link me to it, I'd be greatful.

Comment: @Ernio Just added something to my todo list! Sorry, I don't know any either (yet)